# How to I make sure Rails controller processes data posted to it as JSON?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, controller, webhooks

I am setting up a url to receive webhooks from a third party API, but I am struggling with verifying my URL as required by the API. The API will post JSON data with a verification token to my url, but when I see the POST come in, Rails says that the controller is processing it as TEXT instead of JSON and it appears rails tries to convert the JSON to a hash before my controller has a chance to interact with it.

Here is what I see when the post request is made:

```
    Processing by WebhooksController#receive as TEXT
    Parameters: {"id"=>"5bb2181f-8b7d-4ba2-80a3-072818bb5310", "type"=>"webhook.verify", "created"=>"2014-09-10T22:36:59Z", "data"=>{"token"=>"CWkrAwoPITotLOPQtaiRosOVHPKiOEyh"}, "webhook"=>{"id"=>"5bb2181f-8b7d-4ba2-80a3-072818bb5310", "type"=>"webhook.verify", "created"=>"2014-09-10T22:36:59Z", "data"=>{"token"=>"CWkrAwoPITotLOPQtaiRosOVHPKiOEyh"}}}
```

Which since the above is not valid JSON, leads to:

```
    JSON::ParserError (757: unexpected token at ''):
    app/controllers/webhooks_controller.rb:24:in `receive'
```

I have tested the controller below with the Postman Chrome extension and when posting JSON similar to what I will receive it does successfully return the token in the response header.

I understand that it might be possible that the third party API is not setting the content type to "application/json", and that could cause this, but how can I ensure Rails processes the data as JSON instead of text?

Controller:

```
    class WebhooksController < ApplicationController

      def receive
        raw_body = request.body.read
        json = JSON.parse raw_body
        # Return verification token only once for intitial webhook setup.
        token = json['data']['token']

        response.headers["token"]= token
        render :nothing => true
      end

    end
```

Thank you!

Comment: Could you let it come in as the params[:data] then pull the token after the fact?

Comment: @txdavidtx I tried that as well without success.

Comment: @txdavidtx after more testing you were correct in how I had to go about it. Besides that I needed to try a few things as far as how I returned the token in the response, which is why I originally thought it wouldn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I still am not fully certain how rails is working in this situation, I have found the solution to my problem. Even though the controller code posted in my question returned the results I was looking for in the Chrome Postman extension, it was giving me a JSON parse error with the API I was trying to integrate webhooks for. I instead tested locally using curl and realized that I got the same error.

Here is the curl to test locally:

```
    curl -X POST -H "Content-type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -d '{"id":"evt_REPLACEME"}' localhost:3000/your-webhook-path
```

And here is my updated controller code that worked:

```
    class WebhooksController < ApplicationController

      def receive
        token = params[:data][:token]

        response.headers["token"]= token
        render :text => token
      end

    end
```

It was unclear how the token should have been returned for this particular API, and I was unsure if I should return a response in the header or return JSON or Text. Rendering text and setting the token in the header solved this for me.